# Show that $[(2n)/(p^j)]-2[n/(p^j)]$ is either 0 or 1

Tags: number-theory

I know that if n/(p^j) modulo 1 is less than 1/2 then $[(2n)/(p^j)]-2[n/(p^j)]$ is 0 and if n/(p^j) modulo 1 is greater than or equal to 1/2 then $[(2n)/(p^j)]-2[n/(p^j)]$ is 1

For example,
17/(2^2) is congruent to 1/4 modulo 1, which is less than 1/2. The integer part of 2(17)/4 less two times the integer part of 17/4 is equal to 0.
or
20/(3) is congruent to 2/3 modulo 1, which is greater than 1/2. The integer part of 2(20)/3 less two times the integer part of 20/3 is equal to 1.

However, I am looking for a way to show this is true in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let $u =\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^j}\right\rfloor$ then plainly $u\leq \frac{n}{p^j} <u+1$. Multiply that equation by 2, and the bounds become 2u and 2u+2. If you subtract 2u from that (which is twice the floor), you get bounds 0 and 2 (the upper bound is strict) so it can take in only the values 0 or 1. This also tells you when it's one or the other.

Comment: Could you give some more information as to how this tells you whether it is one or the other?

Comment: This will depend on what half of the interval $[u,u+1)$ the fraction $\frac{n}{p^j}$ lies: if it is larger than $u+1/2$ then upon multiplication by 2, the floor of $ \frac{2n}{p^j}$ is $2u+1$, and so the difference between it and 2u is obviously 1.